# What algorithm should I use for a lot of if else(s)?

Tags: algorithms, programming-practices, conditions

I have to implement a lot of if else statements and I'm thinking of using Decision Tree but I'm not sure if it's going to be the right algorithm.

I don't want to insert a piece of html code based on these conditions.

`directly after an iframe embed (same 300 character rule as columns 4 and 5)
directly after a heading tag (same 300 character rule as columns 4 and 5)
directly after a facebook embed
directly after a twitter embed
directly after a vine embed
directly after an instagram embed
directly after any Oembed
directly after an image
directly after a video
directly after a gallery
directly after a protected iframe`

So I will scan the whole content of my HTML and try not to add an Ad based on those conditions. The rules will grow as well that's why I don't want to use if else(s).

If I'm missing anything please let me know I will provide more context.

Thanks.

Comment: Are there going to be branching conditions? It looks like these are a list of excluding filters. Is that interpretation accurate?

Comment: Hmm maybe I was wrong about the Decision Tree. The list above is just a filter that if the HTML I'm injecting falls into the list I won't inject the code. It's like a Yes/No question.

Comment: What language are you doing this in? A class level list of filters would probably work, but depending on the language, I may be able to give you snippets of an example.

Comment: I'm using PHP. Is it going to work?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know PHP well enough to give you an example, but that doesn't mean that it won't work.

Comment: Can you give me an example from Java or Python? Or any other  language?

Comment: I do not see your problem: the algorithm is simple. Make a Set of objects after which, you are not allowed to place an ad. Iterate over all nodes starting with the second child of a parent Node and check, whether the previous Node was of the type in your set. if not, you are free to place an ad. That should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this,

Define a rule class where the regex expression to detect the tag is specified, and loop through expressions and insert html where necessary.

```
class Rule
{
    string tagRegEx;
    string htmlToInsert;
}


public string Process(string html,List<Rule> rules)
{
    //for each rule, check for regex matches and insert the htmlToInsert after 
    return html;
}
```

Another approach is to use a HTML parser, and use the it's inbuilt function to find nodes and insert your html after them.

Answer (score 1):

As it looks like these are primarily a list of exclusion filters, something like this might get you where you want to be (example in Java, includes calls to functions that probably don't exist as parts of the test):

```
private static List<Predicate<Node>> AD_FILTERS = Arrays.asList(
  (node) -> node.getPreviousSibling().isIFrame(),
  (node) -> node.getPreviousSibling().isHeading(),
   ...
  (node) -> node.getPreviousSibling().isIFrame() && node.getPreviousSibling().isProtected()
);

...
if (AD_FILTERS.stream().map(filter -> filter.test(node)).allMatch(x -> x == false)) {
  // insert the add
}
```